# Extremely Confusing Automatic Facebook Login Recovery Problems

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

Please take a look at the Tinder Facebook Login error recovery image below.

If User change it's password or revoke the permission of the app. The Facebook SDK will automatically present an error dialog like the one below.

[image]

If the User press the OK button, the app will the redirect the app to Facebook to prompt user to accept the permissions again.

[image]

This behaviour/The Dialog box is provided automatically by the Facebook SDK

> To make it simpler to subscribe to best practices, the SDK provides
> FBSDKGraphErrorRecoveryProcessor which can process errors for you,
> such as presenting alerts or dialogs automatically. See its reference
> docs for details.
>
> **FBSDKGraphErrorRecoveryProcessor**
>
> Note that Facebook recovery attempters can **present UI** or even cause
> app switches (such as to login). Any such work is dispatched to the
> main thread (therefore your request handlers may then run on the main
> thread).

I also encounter this behavior in my app, if the User revoke my app permission or change it's password. The Facebook SDK will automatically present a login prompt dialog

[image]

Here is the problem, I have no idea where to specify the readPermissions

[image]

Here is my code which will automatically triggers the Dialog box if the User changed their password or revoked the app permission from Facebook.

```
var request: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: Constants.GRAPH_REQUEST_PARAMETER);

request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        println("No Error")
    }
    else {
        println("Error")
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I specify the read Permissions needed so that the Dialog will request for it?

Where do I specify it?

I have no control over it like I have when I use `FBSDKLoginManager` where I can simply pass in the permissions like the code below, since the Dialog box itself is presented automatically by the Facebook SDK

Comment: Same here. `contact_email` permissions is nowhere to be found on my app's App Dashboard on Facebook Developer and the app does not request them from code. Despite the fact that error message is not presented for "common" user, FB does not log user back in, but logout instead after "visually" successful login.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

`["public_profile","user_friends","email","user_birthday"]`

to this

`["email"]`

Comment: Hi, I am unable to specify the permission like in the FBSDKLoginManager. The FBSDKLoginManager code is the code I use when I logs in. But the error dialog is not and does not runs that code.

Comment: check your app developer should not content contact_email , only "email"

Comment: I don't have this "contact_email" anywhere in my code

Comment: i don't mean your code, i mean your app in facebook developers

Comment: Oh you mean the App Dashboard on Facebook Developer? How do I change it? Where on the dashboard can I find this option? Sorry for wasting your time @Ninja Developers